# Why won´t Atom read my first segment of CSS code but reads everything below it?

Tags: html, css

I have checked the file order and closed off tags. It seems whatever I put at the top of the CSS file will not be read, however, everything below the very top segment of cod ,in this case, #tribute-info will not be applied to the HTML. If I moved #title to the top and refreshed the browser #title will not have its CSS anymore. Same situation for #img-caption.

```css
<style>

#tribute-info{  /* <-- anything I put at the top of the file is not getting read. If I moved #img-caption here, and #tribute-info below it, #img-caption will not work. */

color: blue;

}

#img-caption{

color: red;

}

#title{
  text-align: center;
  color: red;

}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/design.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
         <body>
         <div id="main">

                <h1 id="title">History´s First Programmer</h1> 


                    <div id="img-div">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">


                    <img src="images/ada_lovelace_house_emblem.jpg" alt="Ada Lovelace depicted in an emblem" id="image">


                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <p id="img-caption">The Mother of computer programming</p>


            <div id="tribute-info">

                    <p>“The more I study, the more insatiable do I feel my genius for it to be.”</p>

                    <p>“Your best and wisest refuge from all troubles is in your science.”</p>

                    <p>“Mathematical science shows what is. It is the language of unseen relations between things.
                        But to use and apply that language, we must be able to fully to appreciate, to feel, to seize the unseen, the unconscious.”</p>  <!-- this segment of code is not changing -->

            </div>

                    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace" target="_blank" id="tribute-link">Click here to learn
                        more about Ada Ada_Lovelace</a>


                    </div>
                </div>
         </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Although, you should remove the style tags from your css snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine if you remove the `<style>` tag from your css file

Comment: Removed them, everything is in order now. So when are style tags necessary?

Comment: style tags are used only when CSS is being added to a file that does not have a `.css` extension. For example, if you add inline CSS to your HTML, you would have to use the style tag. For more references, refer to [HTML Styles - CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) and [How To Add CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) by w3schools